# How do I create multiple shapes relative to each other in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to be able to create multiple shapes on my canvas and have them evenly spaced out from each other. I would also like to have the shapes start a new line once they reach the end of the screen.

Heres the code I have now:

```
def draw_streak(self, obj):
        name = obj.text
        can = self.root.get_screen("three")

        with open("streak.json", "r") as file:
            read = json.load(file)

        for key in read.keys():
            if key == name:
                with open("streak.json", "r+") as f:
                    data = json.load(f)

                get_score = data.get(key, {}).get('score')

                for x in range(get_score):
                    with can.ids.my_box.canvas:
                        Color(0, 1, 0, .75, mode='rgba')
                        Rectangle(pos=can.pos, size=(30,30))
```

if `get_score` was 10, then I would like 10 rectangles to be drawn. Right now when I run the program only one rectangle is drawn. I believe multiple are being drawn but they just overlap eachother.

**EDIT**

This is the kv code:

```
<ScreenThree>
    id: screen_three
    name: "three"
    on_leave: my_box.canvas.clear()
    on_leave: selected_streak.canvas.clear()
    ...
        BoxLayout:
            id: my_box
            orientation: "vertical"
```

`my_box` is just the id for the BoxLayout

Comment: What is `my_box` i.e. its inheritance?

Comment: It's just the id for a BoxLayout on my third page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `pos[0]`, `pos[1]`, `size[0]`, `size[1]`

> what does the 0 and 1 in rect.size and new_pos do?

### Kivy Widget » pos

> ```
> pos
> ```
>
> Position of the widget.
>
> [pos](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos) is a [ReferenceListProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty) of ([x](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.x), [y](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.y))
>   properties.

The `pos` contains the x and y coordinates of a widget's position. `pos[0]` refers to the x coordinate, and `pos[1]` refers to the y coordinate.

### Kivy Widget » size

> ```
> size
> ```
>
> Size of the widget.
>
> [size](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.size) is a [ReferenceListProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty) of ([width](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.width), [height](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.height))
>   properties.

The `size` contains the width and height of a widget. `size[0]` refers to the width and `size[1]` refers to the height.

## Create multiple shapes

To prevent the rectangles from overlapping, save the starting position and increment it after drawing each rectangle.

### Snippets

The following snippets add rectangles diagonally.

```
    new_pos = can.pos
    for x in range(get_score):
        with can.ids.my_box.canvas:
            Color(0, 1, 0, .75, mode='rgba')
            rect = Rectangle(pos=new_pos, size=(30, 30))
        new_pos[0] += rect.size[0]
        new_pos[1] += rect.size[1]
```

### Output

[image: Result]

Comment: This is correct except for the fact that it should be `new_pos = can.pos` because the canvas is screen three. Also, what does the 0 and 1 in `rect.size` and `new_pos` do?

Comment: Please refer to updated post for `pos` and `size`. Thank you.