# How do I add padding between shapes in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm creating multiple shapes automatically, but I have a feeling that the shapes are just being overlapped by each other. I want to be able to add padding to the shapes so that this is not a problem.

Code:

```
...

with open("streak.json", "r+") as f:
                    data = json.load(f)

                get_score = data.get(key, {}).get('score')

                for x in range(get_score):
                    self.update_canvas()


    def update_canvas(self):
        can = self.root.get_screen("three")

        with can.ids.my_box.canvas.before:
            Color(0,0,0,1)
            Line(width=5)
            Rectangle(pos=can.pos, size=(30,30))
        with can.ids.my_box.canvas:
            Color(0, 1, 0, .95, mode='rgba')
            Rectangle(pos=can.pos, size=(30,30))
```

**EDIT**

This question has been answered [How do I create multiple shapes relative to each other in kivy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329981/how-do-i-create-multiple-shapes-relative-to-each-other-in-kivy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Rectangle(pos=can.pos, size=(30,30))

Your Rectangles all have the same position because that's exactly what you set for them. To give them different positions, just pass different values for the `pos` argument.